# Map CodeIgniter Validation class to Jquery validation

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, validation, server-side

I am using the CI validation class to do server-side validation and [Jquery validation](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) to do client-side validation. Is there some way I can leverage the CI validation and form building, so that when it is creating the form elements it creates them with `class="<equivalent of CI validation rules>"`? This way, if I change the valiation rules for an element I only have to do it in the CI rules and it automatically changes for Jquery.

Thanks,

Lemaint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make ajax calls back to CI for validation using [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or $.post, that way you only have to create your validation rules in CI.

Here's an example I found to get you started:
[jquery post codeigniter validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331389/jquery-post-codeigniter-validation/2331527#2331527)

---

> Is there a way to map CodeIgniter Validation class to Jquery validation?

Not built-in. Not sure best way to approach this, but you could put all your rules in a [validation config](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#savingtoconfig) file and somehow get your jQuery to parse that file for validation rules when needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution that i know of out there to do this. You would have to create one yourself.

It would have to be a config file that maps what the codeigniter validation is called to the jquery equivalent and then that would have to be parsed for each field.